# Push a viewController from a row in a UITableView within a UIPopoverController

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

So I have a `viewcontroller` in my iPad app.  It has a `UIPopoverViewController` with a `UITableView` inside it.  I want the user to be able to select a row in the tableView and then the rootViewController will dismiss the popover and push a new viewController.  Thanks in advance.

This is what I've tried so far:

In the UITableView class:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
WelcomeViewController *welcomeView = [[WelcomeViewController alloc] init];
welcomeView.whichDay = [daysOfTheWeek objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[welcomeView pushFromPopOver];
```

}

Then in the rootViewController:

```
-(void)pushFromPopOver{
  //PlannerPage *plannerPageViewController = [[[PlannerPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlannerPageiPad" bundle:nil] retain];

    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    [popover.delegate popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:popover];
    NSLog(@"%@",whichDay);

    PlannerPage *plannerPageViewController = [[[PlannerPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlannerPageiPad" bundle:nil] retain];
    plannerPageViewController.dayOfTheWeekString = whichDay;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:plannerPageViewController animated:YES];

    //plannerPageViewController.dayOfTheWeekString = @"";
    //[self.navigationController pushViewController:plannerPageViewController animated:YES];
    //[plannerPageViewController release];
  }
```

The NSLog is telling me what was selected, but the popover will not dismiss and the rootViewController will not push

I though maybe use a delegate but I'm not sure how.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmm…generally you're not supposed to call the delegate methods; that should be handled by the popover itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003701) it perfect for what you need. Your root view controller should listen for an NSNotification and your popover should post that notification.